# Run a cPAddon automatically on account creation?

Tags: php, web-hosting, cpanel

I am working on writing my own system to automatically provision cPanel accounts upon payment.
One of my requirements is to automatically install WordPress on certain Accounts.
What would be the easiest way to do this?
My preferred scripting language is PHP...
I have the WordPress cPAddon installed on my server and I figured it may be the easiest way to do it if it is possible to invoke them via php.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this, so I think it is safe to say that cpAddons are meant to be run manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you?

WHMCS will do the provisioning.  Softaculous will let you install apps.  WHMCS will also provision to Virtualmin, which has Server Templates, which can include apps.

Comment: Well, I am focusing on WordPress and Softaculous is a waste of space / money. This is quite an old post, I have since moved to DirectAdmin.